# how to in include external js file in thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

I have very new to the thymeleaf, and  I am trying to include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

but i am getting the error like:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions. TemplateInputException: Exception parsing
>   document: template="test", line 5 - column 103

and the line number five is the above script So how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `&amp` in place of `&` and put `;` at the end as shown below:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example you can see how to add path variables to a src URL and also how to read environment properties.

```html
<script th:src="@{https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js(key=${googleApiKey}, libraries=places, sensor=false)}"
        th:with="googleApiKey=${@environment.getProperty('googleapis.api_key')}"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```